# 8051 c programming, interrupt progblem

Tags: c, interrupt, microcontroller, interrupt-handling, 8051

I'm programming an Intel 8051 (C8051F312) microcontroller. I just want to make a blinking led program by using interrupts. It compiles, but the led does not blink. Any ideas I would appreciate. Thank you!

My code is:

```
#include <C8051F310.H>
#include <stdio.h>

sbit led = P2^7;        //LED connected to D7 of Port2

void timer(void) interrupt 1        //interrupt no. 1 for Timer 0
{
    led=~led;           // toggle LED on interrupt
    TH0=0xFC;             // initial values loaded to timer
    TL0=0x66;
}

void main(void)
{
    TMOD = 0x01;          // mode1 of Timer0
    TH0 = 0xFC;         // initial values loaded to timer
    TL0 = 0x66;
    EA = 1;           // global interrupt enable
    ET0 = 1;          // enables Timer 0 interrupt
    TR0 = 1;              // start timer
    while(1);             // do nothing  
}
```

Comment: Try toggling the LED in the main loop of your program first.  Is that the right port pin, is it an output, and is the circuit OK?  Are interrupts enabled?  Is the timer enabled?  Does the interrupt ever fire?  Does the LED actually flash, but too fast to see?  What is the observed failure mode - solid on or solid off?

Comment: now I added the line " CKCON=6; " and now it is solid ON

Comment: For testing, you may want to have your timer interrupt service routine (ISR) fire less frequently, say every 500 milliseconds, which makes the toggle of the LED easy to see.

Comment: 2 maybes 1) Maybe re-enable `ET0 = 1;` in ISR.  2) Maybe swap load order `TH0 , TL0`.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it less frequently, but I don't know how! @MikeJablonski

Comment: There's a lot *already* posted here that you don't seem to have tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Mike Jablonski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342288/mike-jablonski) above said, you need to knock down your interrupt rate. Your original code is interrupting at 3.0625MHz / 12 / 922 ~= 277Hz. Part of your `CKCON` addition disables scaling to the timer (by setting T0M), so now you're interrupting at ~3.3kHz. You won't be able to see that.

Seeing anything presumes that you have a functional circuit. You're not configuring your output pin. You said your LED is on "now", but hopefully not meaning that it wasn't before. That wouldn't make a lot of sense since you didn't change anything about what the pin is doing.

1. Get rid of your `CKCON` line to keep the /12 scaling, and reload `TH0` and `TL0` with `0x00` on interrupt. That will get you interrupting at a little less than 4Hz, much more visible.
2. Make that pin push-pull:

   ```
   P2MDOUT   = 0x80;
   XBR1      = 0x40;
   ```
3. Start reading the [datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F31x.pdf) to your micro.